# Android WebView logout and back button issues

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm have an application which uses a login and the webview in my homepage. Whenever i want to logout from the webview the session is just terminated in the webview but i need it to come back to the local login page. Or should i need to write some JavaScript code for the logout in the WebviewClient or should i just need to override the logout URL?

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                    if (url.equals("abc.com") == true) {
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String username = preferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, "");
                        if (username == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And Whenever i hit the back button in the webview page, the page just reloads but does not come out of the application.

Comment: do you want to finish that activity/ fragment containing webview and come back to login screen?

Comment: i need to finish that activity when i logout

Comment: can you post the code you are doing for logout?

Comment: How do you listen backbutton  ?

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } This is the code i have used for back button in the webview